# IONIC2 Cache Management

Tags: angular, typescript, caching, ionic2

I have created an App using IONIC 2. My all pages are requires loading through REST API and sometime it is annoying that geting reloaded in every tab with no updates.

Now I want to improve this by implementing cache to my App. I want it like every http request will be saved after first time with the current timestamp and after 2 hours it will load the content through REST Api.

Any example would be great. I tried using this plugin https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache but there is some issue after installation it was showing error.

Using Sqlite would be better I came to know but I am not very sure and looking for a suggestion by the Experts.

Here is my home page code:-

```
import { WebService } from '../shared/services/web.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    providers: [ WebService ]
})

constructor(
        public navController: NavController,
        private webService: WebService ) {}
loadPosts() {
this.webService.getPosts(query)
                .subscribe(data => {
                        key.posts = data;                       
                        loader.dismiss();
                    }, (err) => {
                        //Fail and log the err in console
                        loader.dismiss();
                        console.log("Some Issue");
                        let toast = this.toastController.create({
                            message: 'There is some issue with network',
                            duration: 10000
                        });
                        toast.present();
                    });
}
```

This is my service provider page:-

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http } from '@angular/http';
    import { Config } from '../../../../app/app.config';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class WordpressService {
        constructor(private storage: Storage, private http: Http, private config: Config ) {}

        public getPosts(query) {
            query = this.transformRequest(query);
            let url = this.config.webApiUrl + `/allposts?${query}&_embed`;
            return this.http.get(url)
            .map(result => {
                return result.json();
            });    
        }
}
```

Thanks Sanny

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Ionic's Storage should be more than enough for this, but if you still want to use Sqlite you can easily modify the following code to use it.

This is just a simple implementation that I've used in a project I've been worked on. I've simplified the code, so please let me know if there's any copy/paste issue...

```
// Angular
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class CacheItemModel {

    constructor(public timestamp: number, public data: any) { }

    public isValid(): boolean {
        if (!this.data) {
            return false;
        }

        let age = Date.now() - this.timestamp;
        return age <= 7200000; // Two hours in ms
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class CacheService {

    private cache: Map<string, CacheItemModel>;

    constructor() {
        this.cache = new Map<string, CacheItemModel>();
    }

    public get(url: string): any {
        let cacheItem = this.cache.get(url);
        if (cacheItem && cacheItem.isValid()) {
            console.log(`[Cache]: obtained response from ${url} from the cache`);
            return cacheItem.data;
        }

        console.log(`[Cache]: empty or expired for data from ${url}`);
        return null;
    }

    public set(url: string, data: any): void {
        let cacheItem = new CacheItemModel(Date.now(), data);
        this.cache.set(url, cacheItem);
        console.log(`[Cache]: saved data from ${url} in the cache`);
    }
}
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory... Basically we use a `CacheItemModel` that will contain the `data` we want to save in the cache, and the `timestamp` to check if that data is still valid. We use the type `any` for the data so we can store any type of data in it.

Our cache is just a `Map<string, CacheItemModel>;` where the **key** is the url where we want to get the data from. So it would be something like `.../api/products` or `.../api/products/5` or something like that.

And then, when you want to use it:

```
public getData(url: string): Observable<any> {
    let cachedData = this.cacheService.get(url);

    return cachedData
        ? Observable.of(cachedData)
        : this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map(res => {
                // Save the data in the cache for the next time
                this.cacheService.set(url, res);
                return res;
            });
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a provider first to implement this code? sorry I am new, not good enough for me to understand.

Comment: Yes, the code of the first snippet is the entire code of the provider, so you'd need to create the file, and paste that inside (should work like it is, but since I've removed some parts to make it simple, there may be some copy/paste issues). The second snippet is how you could use that service from another service / page, when you want to get data from the server.

Comment: it shows error 'Cannot find name CacheService', I have already imported the new file in my service page using "import { CacheService } from 'cacheitem.model';". This file is in the same folder where I am using injectable for my web api. Please suggest.

Comment: `import { CacheService } from 'cacheitem.model';` seems not to be ok... why `cacheitem.model`? This is a provider, not a model...

Comment: I changed the name but no luck, I have updated my question with my code, now please advice me where to implement which part. Thanks a lot in advance.